# Null Pointer Exception while getting Server Date in Volley

Tags: android, date, exception, caching, android-volley

I am getting Null Pointer Exception while getting server date of Cache. I couldn't find relevant solution.

Here is my logcat

```
03-04 14:27:13.960: E/AndroidRuntime(19261): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 14:27:13.960: E/AndroidRuntime(19261): Process: com.****, PID: 19261
03-04 14:27:13.960: E/AndroidRuntime(19261): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'long com.android.volley.Cache$Entry.serverDate' on a null object reference
03-04 14:27:13.960: E/AndroidRuntime(19261): at com.****.FragmentSpecificRestaurant.onCreateView(FragmentSpecificRestaurant.java:170)
```

Here is my simple code

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    long serverDate = MyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().get(url_Getcategory).serverDate;
    if (Utils.getMinutesDifference(serverDate, calendar.getTimeInMillis()) >= 30) {

                MyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().remove(url_Getcategory);
    }
```

Comment: Most likely this part `MyApplication.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache().get(url_Getcategory)` is coming as null.

Comment: I had set false value in shouldSetCache which is the problem. now it works fine.. Thanks mate @SaumikBhattacharya

Comment: You can probably up-vote my 1st comment then! :) Thanks!

Comment: 15 reputations required to upvote comment and i am newbie buddy. Better luck next time.. Sorry @SaumikBhattacharya